# How to confirm that chunk transfer is completed on a DB

Tags: mongodb, backup, sharding

I have one case where i create db for Daily data. I have some collections in this db which are sharded.
My requirement is as follows:
Create every day DB
If There is a DB which is more than 7 days old take its dump in some location and delete it from live DB.

I have one question how can i check if chunk transfer/balancing was completed for this DB before taking its dump and deleting it.
I am concern if i delete the DB whose chinks were not transferred completed will it corrupt my system

Regards
Virendra Agarwal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure there are no migrations in progress while taking your backup, you should [stop the balancer](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-sharded-cluster-balancer/#disable-the-balancer) via `sh.stopBalancer()`. Any in-progress migrations will be completed before the balancer is disabled.

If you want to ensure the balancer is [stopped before taking your backup](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-sharded-cluster-balancer/#disable-balancing-during-backups), you can run the following in the `mongo` shell, which should return `true`:

```
 !sh.getBalancerState() && !sh.isBalancerRunning()
```

After taking your backup, you need to remember to start the balancer again.

Comment: Thats a great answer